# Using a recursive function to dynamically update an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having a hard time getting my array of objects to display and dynamically update.

The expected output would be an array of student objects, that update every 5 seconds. Meaning A new student obj will be added to the array.

This is my function:

```
var students = [];

function getStudents() {
  var student = {};
  student.name = 'example name';
  student.id = 1;
  students.push(student);
  // recursive
  setTimeout(getStudents, 5000);
  return students;
}

getStudents();
```

Right now it creates one object within the array, but stops. How can I make this work? What am I doing wrong?

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/88r0rj8n/2/) to illustrate.

(Thank you for your help in advance)

Comment: Your code works just fine. You only log the array after the first iteration, not each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, I added the `<div id="test">` element to collect the output.

```
<div id="test">
</div>
```

I created some arrays so that I had data to work with.

```
    // Here's an array of students we can add for test purposes...
    // 
    var arrStudents = [ "Rita", "Sue", "And", "Bob", "too" ];
    var arrIDs = [ 123, 234, 345, 456, 567 ];

    // We can populate 5 students with the above data, this will
    // keep track of the number of students added.
    //      
    var intStudents = 0;

    var students = [];
```

I created the function `updateTest()` which is recursively called by the `getStudents()` function:

```
    function updateTest() {
        var a;

        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "";

        for (a = 0; a < students.length; a++) {
            // Append the output to innerHTML
            //
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += 
                a.toString() + 
                ": Student name: " + students[a].name + 
                ", ID: " + students[a].id + "<br />";
        }
    }
```

Now call `updateTest()` each time the `getStudents()` function is called, you'll see the list of students grow.

```
    function getStudents() {
        var student = {};

        if (intStudents < 5) {
            // Add one of the students from our arrays.
            //
            student.name = arrStudents[intStudents];
            student.id = arrIDs[intStudents];
        }
        else {
            // Just keep adding this when we run out of students.
            //
            // We can still use intStudents to generate a unique
            // name and id.
            //
            student.name = 'example name ' + intStudents.toString();
            student.id = intStudents;
        }

        intStudents++;

        students.push(student);

        // recursive
        setTimeout(getStudents, 5000);

        // call updateTest() each time to update the div...
        //
        updateTest();
    }

    getStudents();
```

Comment: Doh! Instead of adding it to the inner html, could I return students? Ie: `return students;` To make use of where ever needed.

Comment: You sure could, the world is your oyster! Or in this case, object.

Comment: Nice! Checkout my edit unfortunately it still just returns one object within the array.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? Your recursive function was fine all along, doubt there's a dude on this site ain't done it at some point. It's probably simpler and cleaner - more maintainable - if you handle what you can directly from within your recursive function.

Comment: @Nuncy yeah dude. much appreciated, thank you for your time. There's still some problems with my inner code that stops the iteration at 2 objects. But that's on me.

Answer (score 0):

> Right now it creates one object within the array, but stops.

The issue is `console.log(students)` is called once outside of recursive function calls. Include `console.log(students)` within recursive function

```
function getStudents() {
  var student = {};
    student.name = 'example name';
  student.id = 1;
  students.push(student);
  console.log(students);
  // set recruive
  setTimeout(getStudents, 5000);
}
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/88r0rj8n/3/

Comment: Makes sense. Would a return function be appropriate here? I updated my OP, please check it out.

Comment: @Modelesq `return` what value? Where would value be returned to? Is `setTimeout` cleared?

Comment: The array of students. If I wanted to call `var studentList = getStudents();` and have the array constantly update.

Comment: What do you mean by "constantly available"? `students` array should currently be available later in `javascript` by referencing `students`

Comment: the students array is just available within one module. If i wanted to use the function elsewhere and invoke getStudents() is what I mean. I feel like returning a value makes sense.

Comment: If `students` is global, that is `var students = [];`, the `students` array should be available when referenced in global scope. _"the students array is just available within one module."_ What do you mean by "module"?

Comment: Hmm. I guess I've worded this incorrectly. I want to be able to return students. console.log works within the function, but a return does not.

Comment: No, `return` would not return expected result, as function recursively calls itself. Are there other portions of `javascript` where `students` is referenced? Is `setTimeout` within `getStudents` cleared? Not certain what issue is?

Comment: Yes. getStudents will be started on load and I want to be able to grab the array of students . Would an outside function like `getStudentsList() { return students; }` be appropriate? Unfortunately that just returns one object within the array.

Comment: _"Would an outside function like getStudentsList() { return students; } be appropriate?"_ Yes. _"Unfortunately that just returns one object within the array. "_ When was function called? Was function only called once?

Comment: @Modelesq At jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/88r0rj8n/4/  `getStudentsArr()` is only called once, before second call to `getStudents()`, given body of `getStudents()` the expected result would be an array having a single value

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'once'. Is that not ok? I just want to be able to instantiate the test variable once while the array is updating in the background with getStudents.

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the value of `students` outside of `getStudents()` at intervals?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120883/discussion-between-modelesq-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 0):

You're only logging it once after the first call. If you move the `console.log` inside the function, it will log the array increasing by one element every 5 seconds

Comment: Hmm if i wanted to retrieve the students array, would `return` work?

Comment: it already works, you don't need to return the students array.

Comment: If I want to be able to call getStudents(); in other modules, I'd like to be able to return the students array. Yes console.log() works within the function, but I want to be able to return the students array.